# Dreaded "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements"

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

i have the "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements" error. The error only occurs when im trying to set TRUE to the Entitlements.plist of get-task-allow. The reason for trying to do this is because im trying to get the device token to be shown in the console, using the device token later for push notifications.

Though, if i set false to get-task-allow, the app would build in the iPad.

Currently using XCode SDK 3.2.3, iPad iOS 3.2.1

I Have tried everything from removing all the keys,certificates  from the Mac. Revoking the certificates in the iPhone Provisioning Portal. Removing the provisioning profiles in the iPad.  Then redoing everything all over again.

I also have checked in the Project "Application" Info that under the Code Signing Identity , it is set to iPhone Distribution : "Name".
Also have checked in the Target "Application" Info for the same thing. Then done a clean build and run but still having this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it, The organiser window of XCode > Window > Organiser . In the Devices tab, when you click on a device that is connected, there is a console pane on the right. you can then use that to find out your device token if "get-task-allow" is not allowed.

Comment: my organizer window in device log does not show anything, just clear white window

Answer (score 1):

The simulator cannot get you a device token, (just in case you didn't know).

On the device, if you have jailbroken it, I am not able to get a token. You need to have an untainted phone.

The error you are getting is because you a selecting the wrong certificate.

Follow these instructions carefully
http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/

Your certificate could also have expired for push notifications, check that as well.